# A good bicycle trailer I can order

Tags: product-rec, cargo, trailer

I would like to purchase a bicycle trailer, to take bottles to the depot and pickup stuff from the hardware store from time to time. What is a good one to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at [Surly Trailer Ted](http://surlybikes.com/bikes/ted_trailer), although I think it is a bit weird in its bike-attachment part.

BOB trailer (as mention in a previous answer) could be a good choice.

Finally, [Extrawheel](http://www.extrawheel.com) is always worth taking a look (their site is a bit ugly, but the product is great!)

Comment: I'm thinking of getting the Surly, I've contacted a dealer and they carry some in my area. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For what you are asking about I would recommend buying a used kid trailer (for about $50 - $150), cutting off the fabric and adding some kind of floor/bin.  Interestingly enough most child trailers are rated for up to 100 pounds were as the BOB trailer is only weighted for 75 (if I remember correctly).

The only advantage of a BOB or Extra wheel trailer is that they single wheel trailers.  This means they can handle faster cornering and are narrower for roads.  They also cost basically the price of a new bike.

See here: [Converting kid trailer to cargo trailer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3390/converting-kid-trailer-to-cargo-trailer)

Comment: I like the idea of stripping down a kid trailer and revamping it, I probably can find one on craigslist.

Comment: +1 for the single trail feature. It is very important depending on where you are going to ride.

Answer (score 2):

[Burley](http://www.burley.com/) is pretty much the first and still a very respected brand.  They make a variety of trailers.

The other major alternative is [BOB](http://www.bobgear.com/).  They make a single-wheel bike trailer that is good for narrow trails and paths or twisty streets.

Note that there are three main attachment schemes.  Most of the Burleys attach to the left rear axle and have a trailer "tongue" that reaches around the left side of the bike.  This prevents making hard right turns.  The Burley Travoy attaches with a clamp on the seat post and has no serious turning limitations.  The BOB trailers attach to both sides of the rear axle, but the trailer "tongue" is jointed so that turning radius is not seriously affected in either direction.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're in Canada, you might want to consider a [Wike trailer](http://www.wicycle.com/index.php) (made in Guelph).  Either the [flatbed](http://www.wicycle.com/cargo_large_bicycle_trailer.php) or the [shopping model](http://www.wicycle.com/cargo_shopper_bicycle_trailer.php) would fit your needs.

The shopping trailer is very similar to their kid trailer, which we have and like a lot.  The wheels come off and it folds flat very easily, you can get a front wheel and use it like a shopping cart, and it holds a lot of weight.  (They say 100 pounds, we've had more than that in ours.)  I'm usually the one pulling the trailer with our kid, and haven't ever had a problem with making hard right turns with the left-side trailer tongue.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a carry freedom, I used the Y frame for a 700mile touring trip and it was brilliant.  It's a simple flatbed trailer which would be adaptable to your purpose.  Totally overbuilt and always felt really solid. The whole trailer flat-packs as well which is handy for storage.

I would warn against single wheel trailers for your purpose as you'll make the bike more difficult to deal with at low speeds because there will be the extra weight trying to pull it over.  Also it'll put more stress on the back of your bike as the weight will be distributed 1/2 and 1/2 with the one wheel trailer instead of 1/3 bike - 2/3 trailer as with two wheel trailers.  The comment above about handling is probably not an issue because I had my trailer up to 40mph and never had any problems.

http://www.carryfreedom.com/products.html