# Making my children's bike trailer more comfortable

Tags: trailer

I'd like to know what I can do to increase the comfort and enjoyment of my two toddlers while riding in the bike trailer, typically for short to medium distances (3-4 miles most often, around a half hour or so).

I have an older model Schwinn two-kid bike trailer, the kind with no proper seat bottom (sling-style).  I have a 3 year old and a 1.5 year old child, and neither really cares for riding in the trailer - but particularly the younger one, who ends up squished.

I managed to fashion a seat out of a piece of wood just the right length to fit on the crossbars, which helped a lot on the squishing, but I'm curious what else I can do safely to increase the comfort of the children.  The trailer specifically says not to use a carseat, and I don't think I could fit two in anyway (or one plus fit the older guy).

Comment: There are a few older model Schwinn two-kid bike trailer, the kind with no proper seat bottom.  Need a picture with your mod.

Comment: When I get home i'll edit one in.  Couldn't find an exact match on the internet, either because it's old enough there are no current-ish search results, or because my memory of its exact appearance is faulty.  [This question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3390/converting-kid-trailer-to-cargo-trailer?rq=1) features a near-match visually - it's probably manufactured by the same company, from what I've read elsewhere Schwinn just rebrands and doesn't manufacture trailers - but mine is just blue, not yellow.

Comment: I did exactly this to our bike trailer, that had the same sling style seat. I presume you've added a bit of padding for the seat on top of the wood. It's funny, my kids just couldn't stay awake in the trailer. I'd put 'em in after kindy and they'd be out cold by the time I was out of the driveway.

Comment: Did any of the suggested improvements work?

Comment: @joe Its over a year later - could you please add a photo of your mod and tell us  how it worked for you?

Answer (score 3):

A comfortable solution we used was to use a sort of hammock for our son. The model of trailer we have is a Croozer Kid, which offers a hammock that fits it frame.

The hammock is attached to the top bar of the trailer, the front bar and the back bar. The third link to the back bar is needed to reduce bouncing. In between this triangle you can then span your fabric, with two soft bars on the side. In the hammock is a 5-point harness to strap the kids safe and tight. Below is a picture of the commercial model

[image: Example hammock for a baby in a trailer]